# Mutate specific columns based on position

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I trying to convert all negative values to 0 in specific columns of a dataframe. How would I for an example convert negative values to zero in column 3:5 and 8 in the mtcars data?

```
mtcars <- mtcars%>%
mutate(across(c(3:5,8), funs(replace(., .<0, 0)))
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(3:5,8), ~ if_else(. < 0, 0, .)))
```

Comment: You can even reduce it further by replacing `if_else` with `pmax(., 0)`.